# Drush commands report "hostname: Name or service not known"

Tags: drush

Many Drush commands are reporting this error once or more:

> hostname: Name or service not known

The commands seem to run fine, though.

This is Drupal 7 running on a local development environment on OpenSUSE 13.1.
The status reported by Drush is the following one. (I have edited out username and password.)

> Drupal version:  7.34
>    Site URI:  http://default
>    Database driver:  mysql
>    Database username:
>    Database name:
>    Database:  Connected
>    Drupal bootstrap:  Successful
>    Drupal user:  Anonymous
>    Default theme:  zen
>    Administration theme:  seven
>    PHP executable:  /usr/bin/php
>    PHP configuration:  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
>    PHP OS:  Linux
>    Drush version:  6.2.0
>    Drush configuration:
>    Drush alias files:
>    Drupal root:  /srv/www/htdocs
>    Site path:  sites/default
>    File directory path:  sites/default/files
>    Private file directory path: ../files/private
>    Temporary file directory path: /tmp

Running "drush up --debug" shows the error message:

> Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-alias-path--c4cc2b4982c6401ca3d49ce3d0e075b4
>   hostname: Name or service not known

How can I fix this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drush calls the `hostname` program to determine if a given fqdn for a remote site alias is actually the localhost.  There appear be other incidental uses for this program, since it is called when you run `drush status`.

If your system is saying 'name or service unknown', it means that you networking is not completely configured on the host server.  This isn't a Drupal/Drush issue, but see:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ssh-name-or-service-not-known-479307/

If that does not solve your problems, try asking in a SuSe forum.

Comment: I can run hostname from the cli. Also, I do not receive the error when calling 'drush status'.  Is there not an issue with the debug message saying "cache-MISS", as opposed to "cache-HIT" on other similar lines?

Comment: Got it... I did not have an FQDN set for the machine's IP, but for 127.0.0.1. Setting it in /etc/hosts fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by updating both /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname. In other words, I ensured that the content of /etc/hosts matched what returned by /etc/hostname.